# Printing identical subnet of IP address on individual lines

Tags: arrays, c, struct, ansi-c

I have a program that asks the user to input a number of ip addresses to be stored in the following array of structs:

```
  struct ipaddr{
    int octet1;
    int octet2;
    int octet3;
    int octet4;
  }; typedef struct ipaddr ipaddr_t;

struct ipaddr addr_array[];
```

I need to create a function that checks for all ip addresses inside the struct array, and check if they belong to the same subnet (i.e. the first three xxx.xxx.xxx of the ip address are identical eg:

```
123.123.123.1
123.123.123.2
123.123.123.3
```

And then for each subnet, the function prints all ip addresses belonging to that subnet on it's own line, e.g.:

```
123.123.123.1 123.123.123.2 123.123.123.3 123.123.123.4
144.144.144.1 144.144.144.2 144.144.144.3 144.144.144.4
```

And the print needs to preserve the order of ip addresses as they were input by the user

So far I have only been able to compare if two structs have the same subnet with the following function:

```
int is_same_subnet(ipaddr_t ip1, ipaddr_t ip2){
  if(ip1.octet1 == ip2.octet1 &&
     ip1.octet2 == ip2.octet2 &&
     ip1.octet3 == ip2.octet3){
    return 1;
  }
  else return 0;
}
```

But I need to do this for an array of structs like so (this doesn't work but it was my attempt):

```
void print_same_subnet(const ipaddr_t addr_array[], int addr_array_len){
  int i, k;
  for(i=0; i < addr_array_len; i++){
    for(k=1; k < addr_array_len; k++){
      if(addr_array[i].octet1 == addr_array[k].octet1 &&
         addr_array[i].octet2 == addr_array[k].octet2 &&
         addr_array[i].octet3 == addr_array[k].octet3)
        {
        printf("%i.%i.%i.%i %i.%i.%i.%i \n", addr_array[i].octet1, addr_array[i].octet2, addr_array[i].octet3, addr_array[i].octet4,
                                          addr_array[k].octet1, addr_array[k].octet2, addr_array[k].octet3, addr_array[k].octet4);
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Any help for a beginner is much appreciated!

Comment: Does not work means nothing. Please say what happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
void print_same_subnet(const ipaddr_t addr_array_1[], const ipaddr_t addr_array_2[], int addr_array_len)
{
    for(i=0; i < addr_array_len; i++)
    {
        if(is_same_subnet(addr_array_1[i], addr_array_2[i]))
        {
            //Do what you want here
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, but I need to print all of the ip addresses with the same subnet from a single array of structs rather than two arrays of structs. So for example addr_array[6] will have 6 ip addresses, and if the first 3 are from the same subnet, then print those 3 ip addresses on one line. If the following three ip addresses from that same array of structs are from the same subnet, then print those on one line

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the array being changed, an approach is to sort the addresses so they're grouped together and can thus be output as a group more easily:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct ipaddr{
    int octet1;
    int octet2;
    int octet3;
    int octet4;
};
typedef struct ipaddr ipaddr_t;

int compare_ips (const ipaddr_t *ip1, const ipaddr_t *ip2) {
    if (ip1->octet1 != ip2->octet1) return ip1->octet1 - ip2->octet1;
    if (ip1->octet2 != ip2->octet2) return ip1->octet2 - ip2->octet2;
    if (ip1->octet3 != ip2->octet3) return ip1->octet3 - ip2->octet3;
    return ip1->octet4 - ip2->octet4;
}
typedef int (*qsort_comparator)(const void *, const void*);

int is_same_subnet(ipaddr_t ip1, ipaddr_t ip2){
    return (ip1.octet1 == ip2.octet1 &&
            ip1.octet2 == ip2.octet2 &&
            ip1.octet3 == ip2.octet3);
}

void print_same_subnet(ipaddr_t addr_array[], int addr_array_len){
    qsort (addr_array, addr_array_len, sizeof (ipaddr_t), (qsort_comparator) compare_ips);
    bool fresh_match = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < addr_array_len - 1; i++) {
        if (is_same_subnet (addr_array[i], addr_array[i+1])) {
          if (fresh_match) {
            printf("%i.%i.%i.%i ", addr_array[i].octet1, addr_array[i].octet2, addr_array[i].octet3, addr_array[i].octet4);
            fresh_match = false;
          }
          printf("%i.%i.%i.%i ", addr_array[i+1].octet1, addr_array[i+1].octet2, addr_array[i+1].octet3, addr_array[i+1].octet4);
        } else {
            if (!fresh_match) {
                printf ("\n");
            }
            fresh_match = true;
        }
    }
    if (!fresh_match) {
        printf ("\n");
    }
}

int main (void) {
    struct ipaddr addr_array[] = {
            { 10, 32, 39, 49 },
            { 10, 32, 25, 95 },
            { 10, 32, 39, 27 },
            { 10, 32, 39, 88 },
            { 10, 32, 25, 22 },
            { 10, 99, 25, 22 },
    };

    print_same_subnet (addr_array, 6);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to build an auxilliary array of same size to note what addresses have already been processed. Code could be (more or less):

```
void print_same_subnet(const ipaddr_t addr_array[], int addr_array_len){
    int i, k;
    int *seen = malloc(addr_array_len * sizeof(int)); // allocate auxilliary array
    for(i=0; i<addr_array_len; i++) seen[i] = 0;      // and set it to 0
    for(i=0; i < addr_array_len; i++){
        if (seen[i]) continue;                        // do not process twice the same row
        printf("%i.%i.%i.%i", addr_array[i].octet1, addr_array[i].octet2,
        addr_array[i].octet3, addr_array[i].octet4);
        for(k=i+1; k < addr_array_len; k++){          // search all addresses sharing same network
            if (seen[k]) continue;                    // ignore already seen addresses
            if (is_same_subnet(addr_array[i], addr_array[k])) {
                seen[k] = 1;                          // note it
                printf(" %i.%i.%i.%i", addr_array[k].octet1,   // and display it on same line
                addr_array[k].octet2, addr_array[k].octet3, addr_array[k].octet4);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    free(seen);          // free the auxilliary array
}
```